# Dynamically specify the controller to use in an Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am looking to specify the controller that a directive should use via an attribute on the element - i.e. dynamically:

**HTML**

```
<div data-mydirective data-ctrl="DynController"></div>
```

**Angular**

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainController', [function() { ... }])

    .controller('DynController', [function() { ... }])

    .directive('mydirective', [function() {
        return {
            controller: 'DynController', // <- make this dynamic

            ...
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
.directive('mydirective', [function() {
    return {        
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
              //Make decision based on attributes or $scope members
              if($scope.$attrs.caseA == 'true'){
                   return new ControllerA($scope, $element, $attrs);
               } else {
                   return new ControllerDefault($scope, $element, $attrs);
               }
         },
        ...
    }
}]);
```

Taking it a step farther, you can use [$controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller)

```
.directive('mydirective', ['$controller',function($controller) {
        return {   
            controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                  return $controller($attrs.dynamicCtrlName, {$scope: $scope,$element:$element,$attrs:$attrs});
             },
             ...
        }
}
```

In both cases, make sure you provide all the specific injectable dependencies (particular $scope, $attrs, transclude function etc...) your controllers expect. More details on controller injectables here [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) under the controller section - ideally, outer controller function should receive them all pass as locals.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the docs about this, but you can do the following. From my understanding this stuff is used under the hood to make `ng-controller` work.

```
.directive('mydirective', [function() {
    return {
        controller: '@',
        name: 'ctrl', // <- attribute that specifies the controller to use

        ...
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach is just use scope since scope is already bound to controller, i.e.
put what you want to call on controller scope and simple handle it in directive link

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if there's any benefit of putting the controllers contents on the scope over accessing them via `scope.$parent` (should probably say this is an isolated scope that I'm accessing via a React component [externally to Angular]).